# How do I get the max id from the first n id's in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the max `id` of the first n id's in a MySQL database table where the ids are not necessarily sequential.  The first n id's are determined by ordering by `id` ascending.  I am using the following query, but this returns the max id in the entire table.

```
SELECT MAX( id )
FROM files
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 8750000
```

What am I doing wrong, or ... how do I do this?

Comment: how do u know which are the first n id's

Comment: The first n ids are simply based on ordering by id ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM
(SELECT id FROM files order by id ASC limit <n>) AS t ;
```

Of course you will need to replace `<n>` with an actual value you need.

Comment: This works.  Thanks.  So in my original query, I'm simply requesting the max id, and my order by and limit statements are meaningless since there is only one result ... correct?

Comment: @T.BrianJones you are right. If my answer helped, you can accept it by clicking on the green tick mark on the top left corner